# Scheduled task to open URL

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

At a certain time each day, I'd like my browser to pop open a tab to a certain URL.

My goals:

1. be able to set the URL from the scheduled task
2. use the default browser (rather than hard-coding it)

I can't seem to accomplish both of these goals at once.  I'll post my partial solutions as answers, but I'm hoping someone will have something better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that this command will open the default browser (or a new tab therein) to the given url:

```
cmd /c start http://example.com
```

To create a scheduled task without the command window popping up:

Create OpenUrl.vbs:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cmd /c start " & Wscript.Arguments.Item(0), 0, False
```

Then call it from a scheduled task with this command:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Path\To\Script\OpenUrl.vbs" http://example.com
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added my notes to the answer.

Comment: @JeremyStein You could remove your notes here because they are already written on your alternative answer, which seems more clean. Thanks ;)

Comment: @bluish, I though dmb deserved the Accepted Answer.  I've edited it to be a clean single answer.

Comment: @JeremyStein mhm, I would reward him with an upvote, but if the favorite solution is another it should be posted as a different answer and accepted. It's just my opinion.. :)

Answer (score 2):

*This solution is hard-coded to Firefox:*

Create the scheduled task with this URL:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-tab http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just create the url file from your script :

```
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile= fso.CreateTextFile("c:\example.url", True)
MyFile.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]")
MyFile.WriteLine("URL=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655253/scheduled-task-to-open-url")
MyFile.Close
```

Comment: I always assumed those were binary files.  I never thought to inspect their contents.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*This solution doesn't allow me to set the URL from the scheduled task:*

Create a .url file pointing to the URL I want.

Create a .vbs script that opens the URL:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """example.url""", 0, False
```

Create the scheduled task to run the .vbs script.

Answer (score 0):

One additional thing to note for the FF solution - if your URL has ampersands in it - you may need to escape those in Scheduled tasks using the caret ^& character.

Oops - this is wrong. 
The ^ was needed to escape the Ampersand when testing the link in a CMD window - but is okay in the actual Scheduled Task.